# Simulating the spatial distribution of water droplets from a dripping tap

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

I saw this pattern under a leaky tap.

(Recreated images)

[image]

---

[image]

---

The pattern was interesting because it looked like a probability distribution. Bigger droplets lie in the centre, and smaller ones scattered outwards (Why?).

It would be interesting to make a simulation of this spatial distribution. There is no specific motivation, just for the pure joy of it.

**So there is a drop crashing on the ground with energy $E$. It splits up into $n$ droplets of random sizes. What would be the probability $P(r,m)$ of finding a droplet of mass $m$ at a distance $r$ from the centre?**

Though an actual solution requires complex fluid dynamics, an approximate solution using stochasticity that still resembles the real case would be enough for the simulation.

If we were to consider the drop oscillations and collision imperfections, it would be chaos. So it is assumed that everything is perfect and chaos doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps as a starting point we may model it such that regions where kinetic energy is greater than surface energy can be shot off

Comment: What surface did the drop fall on (steel, glass, ceramic, plastic)?

Comment: The simplest model is likely to assume a Gaussian distribution of splatter distances. One can complicate this by assuming some distribution of droplet sizes (some skew one with lower and upper cut-offs?) and a variance of the distance affected by size (small ones go further).

Comment: @AlexTrounev Ceramic.

Comment: I think that 1) After splitting, larger droplets might have smaller velocity. 2) It is possible also that a new small droplet merges with an existing droplet, and they finally create a larger droplet.

Comment: If you're satisfied with a phenomenological $P(r,m)$, why not simply make some measurements and fit Gaussians? Remember that some of the large drops are actually smaller ones combined: so you might want to do your measurements one drop at a time - though then the puddle in the middle will be missing (if you dry the surface after every drop) or have a nonconstant effect (if you let it grow as the drops fall). The asymptotic state should be a large and growing, approximately circular puddle.

Comment: I agree with Alex Trounev question. The splatter distribution also depends on how hydrophobic/hydrophyllic the surface is. That not only determines how the velocities of the smaller droplets should be, but also how many smaller droplets it splits into

Comment: The answer to your 'why?' has to do with the stability of water drops. A drop is a mass of water that separates from the rest due to instabilities initiated by non-uniformity in the velocity field (not ideal axisymmetric field). The further a drop goes, the higher its kinetic energy has to be. But higher kinetic energy leads to higher non-uniformity within the drop itself, so new drops tend to form out of this drop as it travels, either bouncing on the surface or in air. The result are smaller drops still. The smallest drops are very stable and can travel very far (neglecting air resistance)

Comment: Just a friendly observation. If the surface is dirty the shapes will change a lot. Like if there is a needle the water will cling to it in the cases I have seen at least ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some conceptual misunderstanding. Basically the the water droplets bounce very similar size droplet back after the fall. This droplet then flies to random direction in almost random angle causing the difference on distance and position of where it lands.

The reason why there is bigger droplets and smaller droplets is that the bigger droplets are created by multiple small droplets landing on the reach of surface tension at almost the same position which causes them to unite.

This is also the reason why the middle "huge" droplet is shaped so variably.
You see on both pictures the standard size droplets; all the smallest ones are approximately the same size.